# Moving node from one jstree to another jstree not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, jstree

Suppose that we have 2 jstree instances. Here `n1, n2` node from first tree and `n3, n4` node from the second tree. I would like to move/drag n2 node within n4.
But it seems the `move_node` method not firing while moving node on different tree instance.

```js
$('#A').jstree({
  "core" : {
    "check_callback" : true,
    "data" : [{"text":"Root 1","id":"n1"}, {"text":"Root 2","id":"n2"}]
    },
  plugins:['dnd'],
});
$('#B').jstree({
  "core" : {
    "check_callback" : true,
    "data" : [{"text":"Root 3","id":"n3"}, {"text":"Root 4","id":"n4"}]
    },
  plugins:['dnd'],
});

//setTimeout(function () {

var a = $('#A').on('move_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
  console.log('move success');
});

var b = $('#B').on('move_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
  console.log('move success');
});

//}, 500);
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.1/themes/default/style.min.css">
</head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>
```

Is it possible to drag and drop node within different jstree instances?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4xg0fsn/)

Comment: Seems like the fiddle is working for me.

Comment: Can you see the console log message?

Comment: @unreleased Is this working for you? It's working for me.

Comment: @FirozTennali can you see console log if you move `root 2` within `root 4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a small correction. You need to initialize jsTree instance at end of the event using .jstree() and call using document level

please make the changes in the code:

```
var a = $(document).on('dnd_stop.vakata', function(e, data){
  alert('move success');
}).jstree();
```

This works fine!!

complete jsfiddle :  jsfiddle.net/thanseeh/o3buztex/14

```js
$('#A').jstree({
 "core" : {
  "check_callback" : true,
    "data" : [{"text":"Root 1","id":"n1"}, {"text":"Root 2","id":"n2"}]
 },
  plugins:['dnd'],
});
$('#B').jstree({
 "core" : {
  "check_callback" : true,
    "data" : [{"text":"Root 3","id":"n3"}, {"text":"Root 4","id":"n4"}]
 },
  plugins:['dnd'],
});

var a = $(document).on('dnd_stop.vakata', function(e, data){
 alert('move success');
}).jstree();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>
```

Comment: mmm I don't think its working . I've changed your fiddle a bit http://jsfiddle.net/37vuda6r/ (only alert instead of console log), please let me know if its alert when dragging `root 2` wihin `root 4` .

Comment: Yeah, it's working. Thanks, @Abdulla Thanseeh. By the way where did you find the event? is it within the documentation site?

Comment: @unreleased i have refered url : https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=event&f=dnd_start.vakata